# How to bring in the original string after comparison

Tags: powershell, active-directory

this is the first time I ask a question. I'm a foreigner and I'm not good at english. so it's a little bit hard to explain my question. Maybe my title is wrong too...
I am trying to compare all the names and info in Active Directory with the time, and then add them to the group,but the info has "WIFI" and numbers，So I a regex the info and compared it with time

```
$time = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
$ccc = Get-ADUser -Filter {info -like "WIFI*" }-properties  name,info  | select name,info
$bbbs = $ccc -replace '\D+([0-9]*).*','$1'
Get-ADUser -Filter {info -like "WIFI*" }-properties  name,info  | select name,info |  export-csv -path c:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "UTF8"
Import-CSV "C:\test.csv" | % {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity namegroup -Members $_.Name}
$bbbs -lt $time
```

The output of $ccc is here

```
name  info
----  ---- 
mike  WIFI-20210515 VPN-20210512
terry WIFI-20210519 VPN-20210519
hack  WIFI-20210530 VPN-20210513
```

The output of $bbbs is here

```
20210515
20210519
20210530
```

But I don't know how to  WIFI-"datatime" is less than the current date, remove it from the group.(
I joined the group using a CSV file)

I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: `-Filter` should be a string, not a scriptblock. `$ccc` will be an array of objects, not a simple string you can use `-replace` on. Please give us an example of what could be in `info` and what your desired output would be.

Comment: @Theo Is it such an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is still very unclear what (date) numbers from `info` you want to compare, but one way of doing what I *think* you want to achieve can be:

```
# get the reference date as DateTime object
$refDate = (Get-Date).Date  # today at midnight

# better keep the returned ADUsers objects complete, with added 'Info' property
# if you want to add them to a Group. By default, Get-ADUser returnes these properties:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "Info -like 'WIFI*'" -Properties  Info | 
         # for convenience, also add a custom property 'WifiDate' converted to DateTime object to compare against.
         # if you need to use the other date (the one after "VPN-"), then change below `$1` to `$2`
         Select-Object *, @{Name = 'WifiDate'; Expression = {[datetime]::ParseExact(($_.Info -replace '^WIFI-(\d{8}).*(\d{8})', '$1'), 'yyyyMMdd', $null)}}

# next filter to get all users that have a 'WifiDate' earlier than today
$usersToAddToGroup = $users | Where-Object { $_.WifiDate -lt $refDate }
```

Now you can add these to an AD group using something like:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'TheNameOfTheGroup' -Members $usersToAddToGroup
```

<sup>Of course, if you want to remove those users from the group, replace `Add-GroupMember` with `Remove-ADGroupMember`</sup>

Regex details:

```
^             Assert position at the beginning of the string
WIFI-         Match the characters “WIFI-” literally
(             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d         Match a single digit 0..9
      {8}     Exactly 8 times
)            
.             Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \d         Match a single digit 0..9
      {8}     Exactly 8 times
)
```

Comment: I tried it, the value of  `WiflDate`  is blank.I will continue to try,thank you very much.

Comment: @Mike It works on the examples you gave us.. If the real data in info is different to that, please give us some real data (sanitized of course)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. emm... I try to give you a real data .

Comment: I want to remove the result of `$bbbs -lt $time` from the group.I don’t know if you know what I mean, because my English is not  good....

Comment: If `WIFI-"datatime"`  is less than the current date, remove it from the group.

Comment: @Mike I seem to have missed brackets in the `[datetime]::ParseExact` line.. Added these now. Sorry, I thought you wanted to add users to a group, not remove them. On mobile now, but I'll come back to this as soon as possible.

Comment: This problem has troubled me for a long time, and it has been solved now, thank you so much